# How to configure Spring Security to avoid 405 Method Not Allowed for PUT request from Angular?

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am practicing Angular + Spring (with Spring Security Basic Authentication).

I cannot make a PUT request to update my entity.

The server responds 405 Method Not Allowed.

```
HTTP/1.1 405 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=90B569C7D540CC684DB87C9FCEEED922; Path=/; HttpOnly
Allow: GET, POST
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 26 Sep 2021 08:24:47 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

There is a workaround by using a POST request. I tried and it worked.

But I do want to know how to configure Spring Security to make the PUT request works.

#### Code from my practice of Angular and Spring:

It is for Angular to send PUT request to the server.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/heroes';

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='
    })
  };

  /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
  updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
    );
  }
}
```

It is the controller for the put request

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = ["/api/heroes"], produces = ["application/json"])
class HeroController(private val heroService: HeroService) {

    @PutMapping(path = ["/{id}"], consumes = ["application/json"])
    fun updateOrCreate(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody hero: Hero): ResponseEntity<Hero> {
        return if (heroService.existsById(id)) {
            hero.id = id;
            ResponseEntity<Hero>(heroService.update(hero), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            ResponseEntity<Hero>(heroService.create(hero), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I figured out the problem and learned 2 things.

1. The path for the PUT request is incorrect. Id is missing as the path parameter. The current code is as follow:

```
  /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
  updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
    );
  }
```

2. I learned there is a DEBUG log in Spring. I figured this problem once I turned on the debug log.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Comment: you should of learnt how to debug your application before you asked on stack overflow. Take that as a future lesson.